# 'aws_amplify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.signUp is not a function'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-amplify

I am creating a sign-up page with React, node.js and AWS cognito.  When handling the signup event I get the error **'aws_amplify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.signUp is not a function'**

```
import Auth from "aws-amplify";
```

```
handleConfirmationSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        try {
            await Auth.confirmSignUp(this.state.email, this.state.confirmationCode);
            await Auth.signIn(this.state.email, this.state.password);

            this.props.userHasAuthenticated(true);
            this.props.history.push("/");
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }
    }
```

An ideas on how resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

I just changed from import `API from "aws-amplify";` To `import { API } from "aws-amplify";`

Comment: For me the fix was changing import Auth from "aws-amplify"; to import {Auth} from "aws-amplify"; Tiny difference but just in case others hit this path too.

Comment: thankyou @nomDePlum!!

Answer (score 2):

Change `import Auth from "aws-amplify";` to `import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";`